# how can I link rows of a SQL table for some columns but not others?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table of values in excel that I want to put into sql as a lookup table. the table looks like this:

[image: excel table in question]

the sql table looks like this:

[image: SQL Table]

having this in SQL, I now want to never use the excel file ever again.
I also need the ability to change the parameters, but some of them in the excel file were linked by merging the cells and thereby shared the same value, if it changed for one it changed for all.
for example: when I change Parameter B for Product 1, I need it to change it for Products 2, 3, 4, and 5 because they share the same cell in the excel table. And if I change parameter A for Product 2, It only changes for product 2 and 3. I am looking for a *SQL Query* solution. I have the ability to change the table structure as well.
Here goes my example query:

```
Update [Table] Set [Parameter_A] = '{new_parameter_tag}' 
     Where [product] = '{selected_product_tag}'
```

except I want to have the `Where` include all the rows that share the same cell from the excel table. 
**I want to be able to update the SQL table for multiple products at a time based on if they share the same cell for that parameter in the excel file.**
here is my initial guess at an answer:

```
Select [{Parameter}],[Product],[Extra_column]
From [Table] 
Where [Product] = '{selected_product}'
```

this returns one row and [Extra_column] that contains a grouping number shared by others in the same cell grouping. this then gets stored as {Extra_column}. then:

```
Update [Table] Set [{Parameter}] = '{new_parameter_value}'
Where [product] = '{selected_product}' Or [Extra_column] = '{Extra_Column}'
```

this requires two queries and also means that i need twice as many columns as i had before. I am looking for something a little more elegant.

---

This is SQL Server 2012 and the {} indicate a value that I am passing in form a script.

Comment: `but now I have lost the information that when I change parameter B i need to change it for product 1-5 but if I change parameter A, it only changes for some of them` - This line confuses me. What you are trying to do actually? Little more elaboration would be better.

Comment: I have edited my post to clarify the problem.

Comment: My question is where do you want the change in the table or excel file?

Comment: in the sql table. I want to be able to update the SQL table for multiple products at a time based on if they share the same cell for that parameter in the excel file. updated question.

Comment: inner join your own table, but make it a case inner join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something similar to what I had above, the user enters the group they want to edit (it's pretty easy to pick out which one you want when viewing the table) as:

```
Update [table]
Set [{Parameter}]={NewValue}
Where [Extra_Column] = '{Extra_Column}'
```

I had to add three columns for the grouping indexes but over 43 parameters that doesn't add much to my table size. I did not take into account the fact that if I change a single parameter for a single product that would remove it from the "group" essentially for just that parameter, and later I would overwrite the changed value if I do a group change for that parameter. I could add in a check to only change values that match within that group but either way the user will have to be smart about what they do. luckily, they can see the table before they change it.